# Word from Db does not equal word from array

Tags: php, arrays

I am searching for a word in my database, when I query it and compare to the same word  from a variable it shows me that the difference is 2 . Why?

```
     $search  = $_GET['src'];
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','search');
      $arr = array();
    $sql = "SELECT word FROM words WHERE word LIKe '{$search}%' OR word LIKE '%{$search}'";

    $res = $conn->query($sql);

    while ($row = $res->fetch_array())
    {

      $arr[$row['word']] = $row['word'];

    }
$key2 = 'phone';
        foreach ($arr as $key ) {
    echo strcmp($key,$key2);
    }
```

And when I search for word phone , i add all the results into an array and then i compare the array keys which are the queryed words with the word i am searching , for this example PHONE.

Comment: 1- Do a print_r of your $arr do see its contents, in that way you will know if the query brings what you expect. 2- sanitize the search variable before using it in the query. 3- rewrite your query as a prepared statement to avoid sql injection.

Comment: When i print_r it shows me the right values , what do you mean through sanitazing and 3 this is VERYYYY beta so i ll implement sql injection later, I just wanna see what it does  not work. I think that in my mysql Table i have spaces in the word columns, can the spaces affect this? For example i edited a word (i just  rewrote it ) and it worked

Comment: That's where sanitization comes in. When you get the values, make sure you don't have spaces and that it is a valid value regarding what you expect to receive. Like not an empty string, if it is a number then it should be composed of digits, etc. to deal with speaces use trim()

Comment: when did you affect the value of $key2?

Comment: @MacBooc look closer

Comment: you just changed 2 min ago :), can you var_dump $key and $key2 and edit your post with the output please? kinda weird behaviour

Comment: @MacBooc Yes I changed it :)) I have already told that this is the copyed one so it is not all the code, anyways i figured it out . I had to sanitize the data. Thanks anyway , Have a nice day !

Comment: @Juan Thanks man , I listened you and now it works! Have a nice day :*